# Elegant way to handle when requests session has expired

Tags: python, session

I'm quite new to development and I use python to interact with a lot of various API's, typically through the requests module. All API's require a login call which returns a session key to be used for the following calls. Psudo-example:

```
req = session.post(https://someloginurl.com, data, headers)    
print req.content

sessionid=12345
```

Some of the API's like to expire my session arbitrarily, maybe 4 minutes, maybe 15, maybe not for the whole script. The response from all of them are different:

```
req = session.get(url)
print req.content

{result : failed, 'your session has expired'}
```

or maybe:

```
req = session.get(url)
print req.content

<xml><result>your session has expired</result</xml>
```

It seems I can't check whether my session has expired until after I've had a failed get request, I would like to then re-login and run the request again.

Is there a better way than the following for every single request I make?

```
def success(content):
    if "success" in content:
     return "success"
    else:
        return

session = login()
while True:   
    req = session.get(url)
    if success(req.content):
        break
    else:
        session = login()
```

or do I make the request a function itself and just pass it params?

```
def success(content):
    if "success" in content:
     return "success"
    else:
        return

def do_request(url, *args) 

    while True:
        if method is "post":
            req = session.post(url, data, headers)
        else:
            req = session.get(url)
        if success(req.content):
            return req.content, session
        else:
            session = login()

session = login()    
results, session = do request(url, "post", data, headers, session)
results, session = do request(url, "get", session)
```

Any advice on a more efficient way to handle this would be greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read!